# Confirm by email when a customer sign up in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used woocommerce and realised that when customers sign up, they can create an account without confirm by email.
What can I do to force confirm by email. Thank you!

Comment: You have to enable this in backend WooCommerce > settings > [**Emails *(tab)***](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/#section-7). Then in **New account** line click on setting button. In this New account setting page, enable the checkbox  "email notification, then save. you are done. As a new user, welcome and [**please do the quick tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it's really fast and you will learn how things are working here on S.O.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this plugin to your website:

https://github.com/wp-plugins/woocommerce-email-verification

And then follow the following instructions:

**Installation Instruction & Configuration**

1. In the admin panel plugins page click Add New. Then click on "upload" link. Select the downloaded zip file and install it OR
   Download the zip file and extract it. Upload "woocommerce email verification" folder  to your plugins directory (wp-content/plugins/).
2. Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' menu in WordPress.
3. Create a page with name "activate". (URL should be yourwebsitedomain.com/activate) and put the following short code and save it.
   [woocommerce-email-verification]

Hope it helps!